# ExtJS controller actions

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, controller, action

I would like to execute Controller code when a Tab is close.

For that I used Controller action with a ControlQuery.
The query seems to be right but the action never fired...

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charlesbourasseau/sU7Me/

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your code is wrong. You've defined a controller method in the view.

Comment: Thanks it works now, I updated the fiddle. So I don't know why my app does not work, but I should find it alone.